# Convert html table to csv in python using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am trying to get table data from a website. The webpage displays some products, I extract the link to these products, and want to go to these one by one, get the table, and combine all information in one big table. The code below returns me information for only 1 product. Could someone help me with extending it to all products? Will be a great help, thanks.

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
def cpap_spider(max_pages):
    global row_i
    page=1
    while page<=max_pages:
        url= "https://dmesupplyusa.com/bath-aids.html?p=" +str(page)
        source_code= requests.get(url)
        plain_text= source_code.text
        soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class":"product-item-link"}):
            href=link.get("href")
            title = link.string
            #worksheet.write(row_i, 0, title)
            each_item(href)
            print(href)
            #print(title)
        page+=1

def each_item(item_url):
    
    source_code= requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text= source_code.text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

    table = soup.find("table", {"class":"data table additional-attributes"})
    rows = table.find_all("tr")

    with open("editors.csv", "wt+", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for row in rows:
            csv_row = []
            for cell in row.findAll(["td", "th"]):
                csv_row.append(cell.get_text())
            writer.writerow(csv_row)
    
cpap_spider(1)
```

Comment: If you have tables, its better to use [pands.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) & dump to csv using [pandas.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: Can i do that for multiple pages?

Comment: Yes you can, keep appending as you crawl using [pandas.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Comment: But there is a lot of other information on the page. How do i ensure that only tables are read?

Comment: read_html will only pick up <table>

Comment: The [doc for open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) said, *w+ will truncate file*, that why you only see one entry. Change the mode to `a` (append) and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate your results from `cpap_spider` and could create a list of dicts that stores all relevant information from detail page. You could get these via `pandas.read_html()` from the table or with `beautifulsoup` from table and all other additional and available elements.

In the end convert your list of dicts into a dataframe / csv or directly into csv.

###### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def cpap_spider(max_pages):
    url_list = []
    page=1
    while True:
        url= 'https://dmesupplyusa.com/bath-aids.html?p='+str(page)
        soup= BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.select('a.product-item-link[href]'):
            url_list.append({
                'url':link.get('href')
            })

        if page < max_pages:
            page+=1
        else:
            break

    return url_list

def each_item(item_url):
    soup= BeautifulSoup(requests.get(item_url).text, 'html.parser')

    return dict(row.stripped_strings for row in soup.select('table#product-attribute-specs-table tr'))

data = []
for item in cpap_spider(2):
    item.update(each_item(item.get('url')))
    data.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('your_final_file.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to that of HedgeHog, but without using Pandas and messier. For each item, I return a dictionary similar to this one:

```py
{
    "Manufacturer": "Medline",
    "Brand": "N/A",
    "Quantity": "No",
    "Availability": "in stock",
    "Weight": "6.500000",
    "URL": "https://dmesupplyusa.com/medline-steel-bathtub-grab-bar-locks-to-side-of-tub.html",
    ...
}
```

Code:

```py
import csv
import logging
import os

import bs4
import requests

logging.basicConfig(level=os.getenv("LOGLEVEL", "WARN"))


def parse_multiple_pages(
    filename: str = "editors.csv", start_page: int = 1, end_page: int = 1
):
    items = []
    for page_number in range(start_page, end_page + 1):
        items += parse_page(page_number)

    # Create the headers by combining all items' keys
    headers = dict()
    for item in items:
        headers.update(item)

    # Write to CSV
    with open(filename, "w") as stream:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(stream, fieldnames=headers, restval="")
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(items)


def parse_page(page_number: int):
    logging.info("Handle page %d", page_number)
    url = f"https://dmesupplyusa.com/bath-aids.html?p={page_number}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    items = [
        parse_item(url)
        for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "product-item-link"})
        if (url := link.get("href")) is not None
    ]

    return items


def parse_item(url) -> dict:
    """From a URL for a specific item, parse and return a dict."""
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "data table additional-attributes"})
    rows = table.find_all("tr")
    item = dict([cell.text for cell in row.find_all(["th", "td"])] for row in rows)
    item["URL"] = url
    return item


def main():
    parse_multiple_pages(start_page=1, end_page=2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is a sample CSV content

```
Manufacturer,Brand,Quantity,Availability,Adjustable,Arm Style,Arm Type,Back Style,Backrest Type,Base Type,Included in Box,Weight,Wheels,Weight Capacity,Style,Securing Method,Seat Dimensions,Seat Width,Seat Width Range,Seat Depth,Seat Height,Dimensions,Cushion Type,Height,Height Adjustment,Outside Legs,Material,Materials,HCPCS ,Warranty,URL,Amount,Height with Seat,Additional Information
Medline,N/A,No,in stock,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,6.500000,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,https://dmesupplyusa.com/medline-steel-bathtub-grab-bar-locks-to-side-of-tub.html,,,
McKesson Brand,McKesson,No,in stock,,,,,,,N/A,0.100000,,300lb,,,,13 Inch Seat Width ,,13 Inch Depth,,,,13-1/2 to 21 Inch Height,,,,Composite Seat ,N/A,N/A,https://dmesupplyusa.com/shower-stool-mckesson-without-arms-aluminum-frame-without-backrest-13-inch-seat-width.html,N/A,13-1/2 to 21 Inch Height,N/A
...
```

#### Notes

- My `parse_item` function is messier than HedgeHod's `each_item` +1 for him
- In `parse_multiple_pages`, I only write to CSV after I collect all items from all pages. That way, I don't have to open/close the CSV file multiple times